# RavenDB replication conflict resolution

Tags: ravendb

I've seen a few examples online, but trying to make the best choice for replication conflict. I would like to make a server plug-in to automatically handle conflicts, where the newest document wins.

In contrast we could handle conflicts on each client, but we have both .NET and PHP clients... It just seems easier to do it as a plug-in on the server?  Can anyone confirm the plug-in route may be the best route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric,
RavenDB has plugin support (`AbstractDocumentReplicationConflictResolver`) to handle that.
You can teach RavenDB how to properly resolve conflicts using your own business rules by inheriting from this and adding the resulting dll to the plugins directory.

Answer (score 1):

Someone already made it for you
http://jtbennett.com/blog/2012/03/customizing-ravendb-a-simple-ravendb-server-bundle-for-replication-conflict-handling

Comment: If you use RavenDB > 2.0 then check the update [here](http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/08/last-in-win-replication-for-ravendb.html)